# Importance of Universal Reference in C++

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

I started reading books and blog posts by Scott Meyers to improve my C++ skills.  I read the blog about Universal References in C++, and I'm trying to understand it.

Is the reason for the existence of this term as a concept because of `std::forward`, or is there something else to give more attention?

As far as I understood, a deduced type with `&&`, called a universal reference, does not always mean an rvalue reference, but sometimes means an lvalue reference. We need to be careful if we need to preserve rvalueness of a function argument, because all the function parameters are lvalues even though they are rvalue reference types. `std::forward` is a solution with these universal references.

Is there something else I am missing?

Meyers dedicated a whole section to this in one of his books, and he wrote some blogs about it, so I'm concerned if I am not able to see the importance of this topic.

Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: Howard Hinnant did a great presentation that, if I remember correctly, covers this. [Everything you ever wanted to know about move semantics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLinb2fgkHk). If I'm wrong, it's still worth the time spent watching and learning.

Comment: FYI, "Universal References" was never an official term. They are formally known as ["Forwarding References"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) instead.

Comment: scott meyers did a great job at convincing others that they need a name. Unfortunately since then two names are around and still articles refer to the inofficial name. To avoid confusion I'd stick with "forwarding references" which is what you also find in documentation

Comment: *Is there something else I am missing?*  You got the gist.  The value is being able to forward lvalues as lvalues, and rvalues as rvalues — which you appear to understand, but not the importance.  The importance should become apparent when you find yourself needing that capability, and then you'll go "ah-ha!"  (Other than Scott's suggested name of **universal reference** was not adopted, and instead **forwarding reference** is used in the standard terminology.)

Comment: @Eljay Thank you for your comment but something got my attention in that. Forwarding rvalues as rvalues makes sense for me because we get rid of the overhead of copy operation of complex structures. How about lvalues? Is it possible to give an lvalue as an argument which is going to be considered as rvalue in the function? Otherway around is possible as far as I know because we can give rvalue to const& rhs which is an lvalue. What is the importance of keeping lvalue as an lvalue? If it is a reference I can understand but if not, I could not get it. Could you help me with that too please?

Comment: An lvalue is something that has storage. Thus, all function parameters are lvalues. A prvalue is materialized during a calculation and is always destroyed at the end of the evaluated expression.
The universal/forward reference lets you know that a parameter has been set by an lvalue or an rvalue. Either way, we can convert the parameter (an lvalue) back to its original form by using `std::forward<>()` inside the last expression used in the function.
This allows, for example, to take advantage of the fact that the source is at the end of its life, prvalue (temporary) or xvalue (`std::move()`)